# Wordpress admin menu limit

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been adding alot of post types and custom menu items to the admin menu in a current Wordpress install.

I've noticed that my posts menu items has dissapeared and a few of the others are also missing.

Every post is registered with a menu position of 5.

I wonder if Wordpress has a limit to how many there can be in each section or whether the pages added with add_menu_page() are actually clashing with the register_post_type() calls.

It's kind of annoying though, anyone else had or solved this problem?

If it also makes any difference, it would appear i'm being limited to 17 menu items, not including the dashboard. This is a number i've seen bantered around a $_POST data limit to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be this: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134

Comment: I managed to solve this myself in the end, NOBLOGREDIRECT helped a fair bit.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding a higher " 'menu_position' => " such as 100, which started the custom admin menu item right at the bottom.